# Как реализовать генерацию размещений С ПОВТОРЕНИЯМИ?

Tags: php

Нужно реализовать на php 
Например: `['a', 'b', 'c']`
Длинна: 2 
Ожидаемый результат: `['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']` 
Должно работать и для большего кол-ва букв с большей длинной

Comment: $result = [];
        foreach (['a', 'b', 'c'] as $key => $v1) {
            foreach (['a', 'b', 'c'] as $k => $v2) {
                $result[] = $v1.$v2;   
            }    
        }  а больше - это чистая рекурсия

Comment: @user334685 прям так только рекурсия?

Comment: @user334685 а можешь написать эту функцию с рекурсией, пожалуйста?

Comment: Вариантов n в степени k, так что можно просто перебрать числа в указанном диапазоне, представив их в n-ричной системе счисления с использованием букв в качестве цифр

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012818/291659 Пример на java

Comment: @MBo Спасибо. Но я по итогу уже реализовал совсем по-другому. Из имеющихся символов рандомная строка составляется нужной длинны, помещается в массив(только в том случае, если такой строки в массиве ещё не было). Далее в обоих случаях рекурсия до тех пор, пока длинна массива не достигнет длинны n в степени k. До 3500 разных значений скрипт отрабатывает моментально. 8000 значений - 10секунд. 16000 значений - думает 30 секунд и ничего не выводит. Понимаю что этот метод не самый удачный и быстрый, но для дз в универе, где при тесте не думаю что и 3500 значений будут рассматриваться - сойдет.

Comment: При таком способе не исключено бесконечное время генерации. Приведенный метод действительно очень прост в реализации.

Comment: Вы правы на счёт времени генерации. По-хорошему стоило бы переделать, но, опять же, для моих целей этого достаточно, тем более что до 10к отрабатывает стабильно, сколько бы раз не запускал.